# Can internal Blu Ray drives rip region-locked Blu Ray discs from other regions?

Tags: desktop-computer, blu-ray, ripping

I would like to purchase a Blu Ray disc from the United States and then use an European Blu Ray reader (internal PC drive) to rip it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AnyDVD HD](http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvdhd.html).
What you want is described here:
http://www.blurayripper.org/

Comment: Software is useless if the drive itself refuses to read the disc due to region-lock, which is what my question is about.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas So, you cant open that blue-ray with this drive unless you hack it. and as it seems you cant. The solution is to find a blueray device that matches with the disk and then use one of these softwares. The hardware solution is possible but needs technical info and hardware engineering. Do you know anybody?

Comment: Could you provide a source?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas what is its model?

Comment: I haven’t purchased the drive yet but assume a standard internal Blu Ray drive for PC: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=internal+blu+ray+drive&iax=1&ia=images

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It seems it cant be done using an software. I suggest you to search for `region-free` drives when you are going to buy. Sorry for that. I will provide some sources in my question which are good to read.